# How to set specific time in postgresql

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to set my database to send a reminder email 2 days before booking.

This is what is currently in my schema:

```
    t.time     "time_to_send_event_reminder",                           :default => '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
```

I've set the table to 23:59:59 which appears to be the highest I can go. How do I set this to 48 hours?

Comment: DB is not the best place to store such info. Check out [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the `send_event_reminder_date` as a `DateTime`, and then calculate the value inside your application? For example:

```
model.send_event_reminder_date = model.booking_date - 2.days
```